# How to extract only hex code from my compiled code

Tags: c, compilation, hexdump

I wrote a program in `C` and I want to get .hex file from it. 
My `C` program for testing:

```
int main(){
    int j = 9;
    int k = 10;
    int l = j + k;
    int m = j - k;
}
```

This is ouptut that i'm looking for:

```
fe010113
00112e23
00812c23
02010413
00900513
...
```

In terminal, I compiled my code using `riscv-none-gcc` compiler with these `--specs=nosys.specs main.c -o main.o` arguments.

But when i opened the main.o file i saw this:

```
��������≤�
������ˇˇˇˇ�|
���� ���t�� ���BFàÅ���ˇˇˇˇ�|
� ���H���º�:���BJàNÅâX»B¡B…B����ˇˇˇˇ�|
�(���|���ˆ�l���BDàíXÅâD¡B»B…B“B�������ˇˇˇˇ�|
�4���∏���
�ö���B BàFâLíìîÅ8
¡B»B…B“B”B‘B�B������ˇˇˇˇ�|
�������î�����H������§�‘���B0BñFïXìîó    ôÅàâíò
B
»F¡B…B“B”B‘B’B÷B◊BÿBŸB�B������ˇˇˇˇ�|
����l��x�������l��z�������l��|�������l��~�������l��Ä�������l��Ç�������l��Ñ�������l��à�������l��å�������l��é�������ˇˇˇˇ�|
������ê������������������������t������������î�����������ò�����������ú�����������§�����������®�����������–�����������‹�����������‡������ ��������������
���������������ˇ������������Òˇ������������Òˇ���î�������������������Òˇ����ò�������*���ÿ��������,���Ù��������?����������U���‹�������d���§�������ã���N�������ó���‡������   �£���†�������¬������������ÒˇÓ������������Òˇ…������������Òˇ–������������ÒˇŸ���®�(����Â������������ÒˇÏ������������Òˇ˜������������Òˇ˛������������Òˇ������������Òˇ��ò��������������������Òˇ��®��������%��§��������8��§��������I��ú��������]��ú��������p��ú��������Ü��®������Òˇò��¯����� �∏��¸�����  �ü��ÿ������“��|������Ë��–�������¯��–��������–�������������� �.�������   �M��î������`��ˆ�l�����¡��÷�������r��º�:�����Ñ�������    �§��é������∆��à������Ï��§�‘�����Ä��™��,�����˝��Ñ��������
�ö�����-��~������M��������  �Y��Ç������{��‹�������á��b�®�����é��x�:�����ì��z������≤��x���������÷�������«��≤�
�����T��‘������Œ��®�������›��‹������� ��������  �‰�������   �2��t�� �������Ä��������å������1��ê������7�������   �N�������   �`�������   ��__call_atexit.c�register_fini�crtstuff.c�deregister_tm_clones�__do_global_dtors_aux�completed.3272�__do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry�frame_dummy�object.3277�__frame_dummy_init_array_entry�main.c�fini.c�impure.c�impure_data�init.c�__atexit.c�lock.c�_exit.c�__FRAME_END__�__fini_array_end�__fini_array_start�__init_array_end�__preinit_array_end�__init_array_start�__preinit_array_start�__global_pointer$�__lock___atexit_recursive_mutex�__lock___arc4random_mutex�__retarget_lock_close�__SDATA_BEGIN__�__TMC_END__�__dso_handle�__lock___env_recursive_mutex�__lock___sinit_recursive_mutex�_global_impure_ptr�__libc_init_array�__libc_fini_array�__lock___malloc_recursive_mutex�__retarget_lock_release_recursive�__retarget_lock_try_acquire_recursive�__call_exitprocs�__retarget_lock_try_acquire�__register_exitproc�__retarget_lock_close_recursive�__BSS_END__�__retarget_lock_acquire_recursive�__bss_start�memset�main�__retarget_lock_init_recursive�__retarget_lock_init�atexit�__DATA_BEGIN__�_edata�__lock___at_quick_exit_mutex�__retarget_lock_acquire�__retarget_lock_release�_exit�__lock___dd_hash_mutex�__lock___tz_mutex�__lock___sfp_recursive_mutex��.symtab�.strtab�.shstrtab�.text�.sdata2�.eh_frame�.init_array�.fini_array�.data�.sdata�.sbss�.bss�.comment�.debug_frame����������������������������������������������������t��t��������������������!���������î�î��������������������)���������ò�ò��������������������3���������ú�ú�������������������?���������§�§�������������������K���������®�®��(�����������������Q���������–�–��������������������X���������‹�‹��������������������^���������‡�‹��<������������������c������0�������‹��9�����������������l��������������    ��<�������������������������������T��`��
���+���������   ��������������¥��}�������������������������������1��y������������������
```

Maybe not a great question, but is there somewhere my compild code? if yes, how can i find and extract or hexdump it? I am using Mac.
 Thanks.

Comment: I don't personally program on Mac, but I think you are looking for the `objdump` utility. You may want to Google that.